# Elastic bounce using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I created an elastic bounce using a CAShapeLayer and modifying it's path. I followed [this tutorial.](http://iostuts.io/2015/10/17/elastic-bounce-using-uibezierpath-and-pan-gesture/)

I modified it a bit, such that it wasn't for a tableView but instead with an edge gesture on the left and right sides of the screen. The left edge is working fine, however my problem is that the right edge doesn't fill the shape layer properly. I've attached a video so it's easier to visualize what is happening.

https://youtu.be/V2eDdH7sHno

As you can see, when the shape bounces back to the left edge, the right path bounces also (I've since fixed that), but it appears the rightShapeLayer is drawn to the right of the screen edge and not to the left. All the control points appear to be working correctly for the rightShapeLayer.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the fill to appear on the screen and not outside of the screen? Thanks!

Edge Gesture Selector:

```
func rightEdgeGestureTarget(gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .cancelled || gesture.state == .failed {

        delegate?.gestureViewTarget(gesture: self.rightEdgeGesture)

        self.animating = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

            self.l3RightControlView.center.x = self.width
            self.l2RightControlView.center.x = self.width
            self.l1RightControlView.center.x = self.width
            self.cRightControlView.center.x  = self.width
            self.r1RightControlView.center.x = self.width
            self.r2RightControlView.center.x = self.width
            self.r3RightControlView.center.x = self.width

            }, completion: { (completed) in

                self.animating = false
                self.leftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.fllscrnRed().cgColor
        })
    }
    else {

        let additionalHeight = max(abs(gesture.translation(in: self).x), 0)
        let waveWidth = min(additionalHeight * 0.95, kCMaxWaveHeight)

        let baseWidth = min(kCMinimumWidth + additionalHeight - waveWidth, kCMaxBaseWidth)
        let locationY = gesture.location(in: gesture.view).y

        self.layoutControlPoints(baseWidth: baseWidth, waveWidth: waveWidth, locationY: locationY, edge: .right)
        self.updateShapeLayer(layer: .right)

        delegate?.gestureViewTarget(gesture: self.rightEdgeGesture)
    }
}
```

Layout Control Points Function:

```
    func layoutControlPoints(baseWidth: CGFloat, waveWidth: CGFloat, locationY: CGFloat, edge : UIRectEdge) {

    let minTopY = min((locationY - height / 2.0) * 0.28, 0.0)
    let maxBottomY = height

    let topPartWidth = locationY - minTopY
    let bottomPartWidth = maxBottomY - locationY

    if edge == .left {
        self.l3LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth, y: minTopY)
        self.l2LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth, y: minTopY + topPartWidth * 0.44)
        self.l1LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth + waveWidth * 0.64, y: minTopY + topPartWidth * 0.71)
        self.cLeftControlView.center  = CGPoint(x: baseWidth + waveWidth * 1.36, y: locationY)
        self.r1LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth + waveWidth * 0.64, y: maxBottomY - bottomPartWidth * 0.71)
        self.r2LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth, y: maxBottomY - (bottomPartWidth * 0.44))
        self.r3LeftControlView.center = CGPoint(x: baseWidth, y: maxBottomY)
    }
    else {
        self.l3RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - baseWidth, y: minTopY)
        self.l2RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - baseWidth, y: minTopY + topPartWidth * 0.44)
        self.l1RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - (baseWidth + waveWidth * 0.64), y: minTopY + topPartWidth * 0.71)
        self.cRightControlView.center  = CGPoint(x: width - (baseWidth + waveWidth * 1.36), y: locationY)
        self.r1RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - (baseWidth + waveWidth * 0.64), y: maxBottomY - bottomPartWidth * 0.71)
        self.r2RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - baseWidth, y: maxBottomY - (bottomPartWidth * 0.44))
        self.r3RightControlView.center = CGPoint(x: width - baseWidth, y: maxBottomY)
    }
}
```

Current Path function:

```
fileprivate func currentPath(forEdge edge: UIRectEdge) -> CGPath {

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: edge == .left ? 0.0 : self.width, y: 0.0))

    if edge == .left {
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: l3LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating).x, y: 0.0))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: l1LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: l3LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: l2LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: r1LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: cLeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: r1LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: r3LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: r1LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: r2LeftControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))
    }
    else {
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: l3RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating).x, y: 0.0))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: l1RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: l3RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: l2RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: r1RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: cRightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: r1RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))

        bezierPath.addCurve(to: r3RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint1: r1RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating), controlPoint2: r2RightControlView.dg_center(usePresentationLayerIfPossible: self.animating))
    }

    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: edge == .left ? 0.0 : self.width, y: height))

    bezierPath.close()

    return bezierPath.cgPath
```

The function updateShapeLayer calls currentPath for the left or right edge and sets the left or right shape layer's path to the returned cgPath.

The dg_center function is an extension on UIView and can be read about in the tutorial link above.